# Docker Firestore project id is required

Tags: firebase, docker, go, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm getting started with Docker and I have a simple image where I want to run a Go script.

Here's the image:

```
FROM golang:alpine

ENV GO111MODULE=on \
  CGO_ENABLED=0 \
  GOOS=linux \
  GOARCH=amd64

WORKDIR /build

COPY go.* ./
RUN go mod download

COPY . ./

RUN go build -o main .

WORKDIR /dist

RUN cp /build/main .

CMD ["/dist/main"]
```

My Go code section that's giving me issues is here:

```
opt := option.WithCredentialsFile("my-app-firebase-adminsdk.json")
app, err := firebase.NewApp(context.Background(), nil, opt)

client, err := app.Firestore(context.Background())

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("error initializing app:", err)
}
```

This runs fine when I run `go install && my-app`

When I try to run it in a Docker container I get the following error message.

> error initializing app: project id is required to access Firestore

This must mean that the `my-app-firebase-adminsdk.json` file isn't being included in the Docker container.

How do I solve this?

I've tried adding `COPY my-app-firebase-adminsdk.json .` under the `COPY go.* ./` line but that didn't help, ended up having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have to be all complicated. It worked when I used a simple `Dockerfile` as follows:

```
FROM golang:alpine

RUN mkdir /app

ADD . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN go build -o main .

CMD ["/app/main"]
```